# Getting selected option change jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, select

I have a [table editable](http://jsfiddle.net/Manna/cpRa2/9/) with an Invoice calculator. I have a small issue in my select editable. If you click on *IVA 21 %* you notice that you can select the option *IVA none*, i need that once i selected the option *none* in my select editable, it does not automatically calculate my IVA. I do not how to manage it, or setting an on change jQuery  or a submit, in both cases i was not able to do it!.

The calculator works, if you select no Iva and then you clone a row clicking on +, the IVA is not calculated but i want to achieve it the same once i select the option NO IVA.

This the code :

```
if ($('.editable_selectiva').text() === "NO IVA") {
            $('#total').html(0);
            $('#total1').html(total);
        }
        else {
            $('#total').html(total*0.21);
            $('#total1').html(total*1.21);
        }
    })
}
```

Hope the explanation is clear and you can help me out. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bind a change event to the select. Add this code

```
$('p.editable_selectiva').change(function() {
    tally('p#subtotal');
    tally('p#total');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

```
$('.editable_selectiva select').change(function(){
    tally('p#subtotal');
    tally('p#total');
});
```